# Javascript showing the biggest number

Tags: javascript, html

script which loads consecutive numeric values until 0 is encountered, then find the highest value among the given numbers my script below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<!---Napisz skrypt który pozwoli na wczytanie kolejnych wartości liczbowych aż do napotkania 0 następnie
wsród podanych liczb znajdź wartość największą-->
<script>

let tab = [], i = 0, max, min;
//wczytywanie danych
do
{

tab[i] = parseInt(prompt("Podaj jakąś wartość. \n Zero kończy wprowadzanie danych:"));
i++;
}
 while(tab[i-1]);
 max = tab[0]; min = tab[0];
 for(i=1; i < tab.length-1; i++)
{
    if(tab[i]>max) max = tab[i];

}
document.write()

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix it?

if,else it should show the biggest and the lowest typed number

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const numbers = []
while(true) {
 const num = parseInt(prompt('Insert a number. zero to exit'))
 if(num === 0){
  break;
 }
 numbers.push(num)
 
 console.log(`the max number entered is ${Math.max(...numbers)}`)
 console.log(`the min number entered is ${Math.min(...numbers)}`)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) is easy to write in your code, but the experience it creates for the user can be quite disruptive. From the linked MDN documentation:

> Dialog boxes are modal windows; they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed. For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a dialog box (or modal window).

In the case of your question, making use of a [number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) provides multiple advantages (non-blocking, built-in validation, etc.)

Here's an example of using a number input element and keeping track of the user's input history, which allows for an always updated value for min and max as the user commits new values:

> If you want to prevent input of duplicate values, you could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an array.

```js
const numbersElm = document.getElementById('numbers');
const minElm = document.getElementById('min');
const maxElm = document.getElementById('max');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const state = {
  numbers: [],
  min: NaN,
  max: NaN,
};

// Allow the user to commit values using the keyboard's Enter key:
input.addEventListener('keyup', (ev) => {
  if (ev.key === 'Enter') handleCommit();
});

// Or by clicking the button:
button.addEventListener('click', handleCommit);

function updateOutput () {
  numbersElm.textContent = state.numbers.join(', ');
  if (Number.isFinite(state.min)) minElm.textContent = state.min;
  if (Number.isFinite(state.max)) maxElm.textContent = state.max;
}

function parseInput () {
  const trimmed = input.value.trim();

  // Avoid invalid (or a lack of) input:
  if (!trimmed) return NaN;
  const number = Number(trimmed);
  if (Number.isNaN(number)) return NaN;

  // You can return the valid number now:
  // return number;

  // Or convert it to an integer first:
  return parseInt(number, 10);
}

function handleCommit () {
  const number = parseInput();

  // Cancel if the input is not valid:
  if (Number.isNaN(number)) {
    // Select the value in the input
    // so that the user can overwrite it easily (or modify it):
    input.select();
    return;
  }

  state.numbers.push(number);
  state.min = Math.min(...state.numbers);
  state.max = Math.max(...state.numbers);
  updateOutput();

  // Clear the input so that the user doesn't have to:
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; } body, button { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 1rem; } input[type="number"], #numbers { font-family: monospace; } button, input { font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; } #output { margin-bottom: 1rem; display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 1rem; }
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div id="numbers">Commit a number to get started</div>
  <div>Min: <span id="min"></span></div>
  <div>Min: <span id="max"></span></div>
</div>
<input type="number" />
<button>Commit number</button>
```